# Flash with background image

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, pageload

I'm  a youger web-designer and I have some problem with a background image. When i load a page with a background-image start a quick flash of the color of the background.
I have this problem only with google chrome and not with firefox or edge.

Can you help me please??

I use this syntax

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 300;
background: url(../img/background.jpg) fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: what google chrome version?

Comment: Version 50.0.2661.102 m

Comment: could you please show the snapshot of your page.